# Power BI Calculate distinct impacting when I use filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, daxstudio

I made a measure that is as follows:

```
wo = CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT('Table1'[won]),
ALLEXCEPT(Table1, 'Table1'[flag]),
ALLEXCEPT(Calendar,Calendar[End of Week]),
FILTER(Table1,[flag]="Y")
)
```

I want the total amount of items in 'won' column with the flag = 'Y'. But when I use one date range filter [End of Week] I had problem because my total amount keeps changing and shouldn't change, I want the total of my entire table regardless of date.

This measure works without 'Y' flag, but it's not what I need:

```
wo= CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT('Table1'[wo]),
ALL(Calendar)
)
```

Could you please help me how to adjust this measure?

Comment: I don't understand.  `ALLEXCEPT(Calendar,Calendar[End of Week]),` removes all the filters on Calendar except filters on `End of Week`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allexcept-function-dax  Which sounds like what you describe.

Comment: I already tried without this column and it's keep impacting my value.

Comment: What if you add the `FILTER(Table1,[flag]="Y")` to the measure with `ALL(Calendar)`?

Comment: Still with the same problem. My result must be 4026 (total values in a column in a table (distinct)). When I'm using a date slicer, it's changing over time.

Comment: So try to replicate it with a minimal repro using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-enter-data-directly-into-desktop and post the data and desired results

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this DAX CODE:

```
wo= CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table1'[won]),
    FILTER(ALL(Table1),[flag]="Y")
)
```